# no IPV6 via Mobile Hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot, ipv6

I have two Android phones. Same hardware model, one with android 10 and the other with 11.
Both phones connect to the same telco.
On both phones I can browse to [test-ipv6.com](https://test-ipv6.com) and get a 10/10 indicating IPV6 on each handset is working.
I then enable mobile hotspot and test from my laptop.
Via the android 10 phone the laptop receives a V6 IP and the above website reports a 10/10 from the laptop
Via the android 11 phone, the laptop does not get a V6 IP, and the above website report 0/10.

I have looked though as many settings on Android 11 handset as I can, and scoured the internet for ideas but I cannot determine why a V6 IP is not allocated from the 11 handset.

Ideas?

Comment: Which device model are you talking about? Are both phone non-branded? Some times manufacturer introduce bugs in new (major) Android versions, if the device is the same this could be such a case.

Comment: Both are samsung a31

Comment: Can confirm, IPv6 via hotspot on my A52s with Android 11 does not work.

Comment: Thanks for dropping the comment. It looks like a regression in the version upgrade.